# Find record with maximum value in related table

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

How do I get the USER_PASSWORD ID of the most recently created user_password for each user?

USER Table

| USER_ID | USERNAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | USER1 |
| 2 | USER2 |
| 3 | USER3 |

USER_PASSWORD Table

| ID | USER_ID | PASSWORD | CREATED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | PASSWORD1 | 2020-01-01 |
| 2 | 1 | PASSWORD2 | 2020-02-01 |
| 3 | 1 | PASSWORD3 | 2020-03-01 |
| 4 | 2 | PASSWORD4 | 2020-04-01 |
| 5 | 2 | PASSWORD5 | 2020-05-01 |
| 6 | 2 | PASSWORD6 | 2020-06-01 |
| 7 | 3 | PASSWORD7 | 2020-07-01 |
| 8 | 3 | PASSWORD8 | 2020-08-01 |
| 9 | 3 | PASSWORD9 | 2020-09-01 |

Currently I'm using the sloppy query below

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM USER) USERS
    JOIN (SELECT USER_ID, MAX(CREATED) MAX FROM USER_PASSWORD GROUP BY USER_ID) MAXPASSWORDS
         ON USERS.USER_ID = MAXPASSWORDS.USER_ID
    JOIN (SELECT * FROM USER_PASSWORD) PASSWORDS
         ON USERS.USER_ID = PASSWORDS.USER_ID AND MAXPASSWORDS.MAX = PASSWORDS.CREATED
ORDER BY USERS.USERNAME;
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `FROM (SELECT * FROM USER) USERS` can be simplified to `FROM
USER USERS`

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Why is `ID` 1 in `USER_PASSWORD`? typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the join, you can specify the `max` function as below.

```
select u.user_id, up.id as user_password_id, up.created
from users u 
inner join user_passwords up 
  on up.user_id = u.user_id 
  and up.created = (
    select max(created) from user_passwords where user_id = u.user_id
  );
```

So basically when doing the join, it will find the latest password created (`max(created)`) for each user who is being joined.

Working example [@DB Fiddle on Postgres 12](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wCj1PzMueNLTsJiQ6fUPGx/3)

Comment: The query by @atish.s also works in Oracle. But not so much the fiddle. See [working Oracle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=98970b4d18b5da61d0c7931eec096d85) that implements the exact same query.